# django - My form wont save an added M2M object. Why?

Tags: python, django

My code:

```
class DataSourceCreateView(CreateView):
    model = DataSource
    form_class = DataSourceForm
    template_name = 'engine/datasource_create.html'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):

        f = form.save(commit=False)
        f.creator = self.request.user

        f.save()
        dsr_pk = form.cleaned_data['dataset_request']
        if dsr_pk != 'noval':
            print(dsr_pk)
            dsr = DatasetRequest.objects.get(pk=dsr_pk)
            f.dataset_requests.add(dsr)
            print(f)
            print(f.dataset_requests)
            f.save()

        return super(DataSourceCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

why isn't my form adding `dsr` to `f.dataset_requests`? The form saves and goes on without adding `dsr` to `f.dataset_requests`. I made the dataset_request field into a single select field instead of a multiple select field in DataSourceForm. Thanks in advance

Comment: try to add " f.same_m2m()" after save form

Comment: 'DataSource' object has no attribute 'save_m2m'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up overriding the save method of my DataSourceForm to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `save_m2m` for saving ManyToMany relation. You can try like this:

```
class DataSourceCreateView(CreateView):
    model = DataSource
    form_class = DataSourceForm
    template_name = 'engine/datasource_create.html'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):

        f = form.save(commit=False)
        f.creator = self.request.user
        f.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())  # Not calling Super here
```

Comment: I'm getting "'DataSource' object has no attribute 'save_m2m'"

Comment: Updated my answer @MikeJohnsonJr

Comment: the form saves but the m2m does not save, I've tried this before

Comment: did you get any error? How did you test your code if it worked or not? Finally, if its possible, then please share your model and form